# Get parts of a string with preg_replace()

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to get regex pattern and target url from the following string :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo.php
```

In the string above

The pattern is : ^(.*)$

And target is : /demo.php

I have tried the following code, but the result was blank.

```
$x="RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo.php";

preg_replace("/RewriteRule\s+(.+?)\s+(.+)/i","<b>pattern :</b>$1<br><b>target:</b>$2",$x);
```

Is there something wrong with the function?

My expected output should be :

**pattern  :** ^(.*)$

**target  :** /demo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure on $x you use single quotes ' ' (not double to not interpretate the $ sign)

I tested your example and it looks ok.

If you echo the result of preg_replace should be the output you want. Check here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c1a86509d4a3b31fb132643e6796ef364321946

Comment: I have already tested it many times on my site. It doesnt work. I have php 5.4.17, i think there is something wrong with the php version.